# Multiple document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-selectors

I have an image zoomer that I am using in a modal. The zoomer plugin uses an `document.getElementById` to open the image but I need it to open multiple images.

I have read many of your posts that say I need to use other selectors such as

```
(document.querySelectorAll("#galley1, #galley2, #galley3));
```

or a class selector

```
(document.getElementsByClassName("galley"));
```

I have tried these but still can't get it to open the image zoomer with multiple ID's.

The ID I am using on the divs and for the selector are #galley1, #galley2, #galley3.

You can see the entire code at my website http://www.fitzgeraldoilworks.com. The first image on the page works perfect but the rest of the images will not zoom in the modal.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />

<title>Photo Zoom</title>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lity.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/viewer.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lity.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/viewer.js"></script>

</head>


<body>

<div class="featured-body-wrap">
  <div class ="featured-image-container"> 


       <div class ="featured-image-holder">
           <div class="featured-title">KINGS CHOICE</div>

        <div class ="featured-image-wrap">
            <a href="#kings" data-lity> <img src="images/art/thmb/kings choice320.jpg" 
            class="featured-image" style="width:100%;height:auto;border:0;"/></a>
        </div>
       </div>

<div id="kings" class="lity-hide">
<div id="galley1">

          <div class="modal-img-container">

                           <div class="modal-header">Kings Choice</div>

              <div class="sized-box">
                 <div class="model-img-wrap"><img class="model-img" 
                 data-original="images/art/hires/kings choice1500.jpg" src="images/art/med/kings choice700.jpg" alt="SCROLL MOUSE TO ZOOM"/></div>
              </div>
              <div class="sized-box">
                 <div class="model-img-wrap"><img class="model-img" 
                 data-original="images/art/hires/kings choice wall1500.jpg" src="images/art/med/kings choice wall700.jpg" alt="SCROLL MOUSE TO ZOOM"/></div>
              </div>
              <div class="sized-box">
                 <div class="model-img-wrap"><img class="model-img" 
                 data-original="images/art/hires/kings choice head1400.jpg" src="images/art/med/kings choice head700.jpg" alt="SCROLL MOUSE TO ZOOM"/></div>
              </div>

          </div>
</div>
</div>


       <div class ="featured-image-holder">
           <div class="featured-title">WISPER</div>

        <div class ="featured-image-wrap">
            <a href="#wisper" data-lity> <img src="images/art/thmb/wisper thmb320.jpg" 
            class="featured-image" style="width:100%;height:auto;border:0;"/></a>
        </div>
       </div>

<div id="wisper" class="lity-hide">
<div id="galley2">

          <div class="modal-img-container">

                           <div class="modal-header">WISPER</div>

              <div class="sized-box">
                 <div class="model-img-wrap"><img class="model-img" 
                 data-original="images/art/hires/wisper hires.jpg" src="images/art/med/wisper md.jpg" alt="SCROLL MOUSE TO ZOOM"/></div>
              </div>
              <div class="sized-box">
                 <div class="model-img-wrap"><img class="model-img" 
                 data-original="images/art/hires/wisper face hires.jpg" src="images/art/med/wisper face md.jpg" alt="SCROLL MOUSE TO ZOOM"/></div>
              </div>
              <div class="sized-box">
                 <div class="model-img-wrap"><img class="model-img" 
                 data-original="images/art/hires/wisper wall hires.jpg" src="images/art/med/wisper wall md.jpg" alt="SCROLL MOUSE TO ZOOM"/></div>
              </div>

          </div>
</div>
</div>

        <div class ="featured-image-wrap">
            <a href="#shadow" data-lity> <img src="images/art/thmb/shadow thmb.jpg" 
            class="featured-image" style="width:100%;height:auto;border:0;"/></a>
        </div>
       </div>

<div id="shadow" class="lity-hide">
<div id="galley3">

          <div class="modal-img-container">

                           <div class="modal-header">SHADOW</div>

              <div class="sized-box">
                 <div class="model-img-wrap"><img class="model-img" 
                 data-original="images/art/hires/shadow-hires.jpg" src="images/art/med/shadow-md.jpg" alt="SCROLL MOUSE TO ZOOM"/></div>
              </div>
              <div class="sized-box">
                 <div class="model-img-wrap"><img class="model-img" 
                 data-original="images/art/hires/shadow-easle-hires.jpg" src="images/art/med/shadow-easle-md.jpg" alt="SCROLL MOUSE TO ZOOM"/></div>
              </div>
              <div class="sized-box">
                 <div class="model-img-wrap"><img class="model-img" 
                 data-original="images/art/hires/shadow-wall-hires.jpg" src="images/art/med/shadow-wall-md.jpg" alt="SCROLL MOUSE TO ZOOM"/></div>
              </div>

          </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>




      <script type="text/javascript">

    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      var galley = (document.querySelectorAll("#galley1, #galley2, #galley3"));
      var viewer = new Viewer(galley, {
        url: 'data-original',
        button: true,
        navbar: false,
        title: true,
        toolbar: false,
        tooltip: true,
        movable: true,
        zoomable: true,
        scalable: true,
        transition: true,
        zoomRatio: 0.3,
        minZoomRatio: 0.01,
        maxZoomRatio: 100,
        zIndex: 2015,
        inline: false,
        minWidth: 200,
        minHeight: 100,
        viewed: function () {
var context = this;
$('.viewer-canvas').click(function(e){
if(e.target.className == 'viewer-canvas') {
context.viewer.hide();
}
});
}
      });
    });

          </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Place all your images under 1 class, for example "images".
Then do

```
var myImages = document.getElementsByClassName("images");
```

You'll get an array containing all your images.
If you want to do this with ids, then give your images ids like "img1","img2","img3" Then do

```
var myImages = [];
for(var i = 0; i < numImages; i++) {
    myImages.push(document.getElementById("img"+i));
}
```

he result should be the same.

Comment: My images already have a class of "model-img". I changed the script to       var myImages = document.getElementsByClassName("model-img");
but it still did not work.

Comment: I think your plugin just takes a single image to zoom. So you can pass an element from your array. For example myImages[0] (this shoud be the first element).

Comment: Yes I think you are correct but I do not know how to implement this and would need an example to understand how to do this,,,,, but I do appreciate your help and Thank You...!

Answer (score 0):

Your image viewer script probably does not handle multiple elements being passed into it. You will have to initialize it separately for every element:

```
var $elements = document.querySelectorAll('...');

for (var i = 0; i < $elements.length; i++) {
    var viewer = new Viewer($elements[i], {...});
}
```

Comment: I would like to try this but am unsure of how to add this to my script. I wish I had an example.

Comment: Also I think you are correct. I am using a plugin called viewerJS and on there document page they indicate that this viewer can be used in modals and give the code...... I just don't know how to implement it into my script. Sorry I am not very good at javascript. Here is the code on there document page. It is VERY simular to yours. 
var viewer;

image.addEventListener('viewed', function () {
  console.log(this.viewer === viewer);
  // -> true
}, false);

viewer = new Viewer(image);

Comment: @MichaelFitzgerald: I'm not sure what you mean, I just added ellipses in place of the parts that were too long to type out. It should work if you replace them with the actual values contained in your code.

Comment: Sorry. I do not mean to be confusing. It's just that I lack the knowledge on how to implement this part of the code into my javascript. But I do think this is the right direction.

Comment: Is it possible for you to take the javascript at the end of my page and implement this code into it as an example so that I can see how it is done. I think I would then know what code to put into the ellipses as you have indicated.

Comment: I was unable to implement this code because I lack the knowledge on how to do this but I do want to say thank Blender for all your help and effort.... I do very much appreciate it.